# How do I change the style of app icons in chrome://apps?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-extensions, browser-addons, css

Like the title says, I'd like to change the style of app icons in `chrome://apps`. I know exactly what rule I want changed and what I want it changed to, but I don't know how to change it other than going through the element inspector and doing it manually.

[image: What it's like now]

[image: What I want it to be]

How do I change this rule? I started with the styleish and stylebot extensions, which didn't work, then tried reading through the possible style properties in the google chrome theme manifest.json, but couldn't find any documentation of any that would affect the app icons. I also tried rummaging through my chrome folder in application support, but I couldn't find the stylesheet responsible for this. Where is this stylesheet coming from? Is it in a binary? Is it being generated? Any guesses/ideas about how to change this would be appreciated.